# Loop shell script if the input file has more inputs

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have a shell script and I have provided answers for the script through answers.txt file.

```
echo -n "Enter your name: "; read name
echo -n "Enter your number: "; read number
echo "Your name is $name and your number is $number"
```

answers.txt file

```
Buvanesh
12345
```

I run this script using `script.sh < answers.txt`

The answer file is dynamic, means user can add more names and numbers in the answer file.

e.g.

```
Buvanesh
12345
Kanna
45678
```

In that case, if I run the script it will take only first two inputs.
I want to take shell script all inputs and give output accordingly. I guess I have to implement a loop, but I don't know exactly how to for this case. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: welcome to U&L stack exchange! Don't forget to up-vote answers that helped you, and select the one you like best with the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r name && IFS= read -r number; do
   #IFS= read -r number || break
   printf 'Your name is %s and your number is %d\n' "$name" "$number"
done < answers.txt
```

Your thought processes were on the right track, we need to bring in a `loop`, the `while` loop whose condition are `read` commands joined by an AND.

Comment: `while read name && read number` ?

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for the updates. I have included the changes recommended.

Comment: and along roaima's comment on mine, incorporate the -p prompt string, if the OP really wants it

Answer (score 0):

The `read` command will fail when there's no more input, so you could use it as the looping condition:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Enter your name: "
while read name
do
  echo -n "Enter your number: "
  read number
  echo "Your name is $name and your number is $number"
done
```

Comment: Though this doesn't check if the `number` line gets read correctly

Comment: @ilkkachu `read number || break` perhaps. With an extra `echo -n "Enter your name: "` at the end of the loop. Better still, incorporate the prompt in the `read` itself, `while read -p "Enter your name: " name && read -p "Enter your number: " number; do ... done`

Comment: @Shaller, I have applied your concept in following script. But not working :(.  https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/WC82OGzO0ez~Z92WVi1biV5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=/raw

Comment: that looks like completely different input than your original question

Comment: @Jeff I have applied Rakesh answer. It's working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Schaller's answer is good.  The downside of redirecting input from a file is that your manual input is now also subject to the loop so that users will have to know to hit enter (not provide a value) to end the loop. You might use your current logic for manual runs and do something like below when there is an input file ($1) supplied to the script (not redirected).

If you are confident that the format of the file will always be "name\nnumber\n" then you could do:

```
cntr=0
cat $1 | while read line
do
    if [ $cntr -eq 0 ]
    then
      name=$line
      cntr=1
    elif [ $cntr -eq 1 ]
      number=$line
      echo "Your name is $name and your number is $number"
      cntr=0
    fi
done
```

This should print your statement until all name/number combinations have been read.